# Heroku not starting workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, resque

My Heroku app is not starting any workers. I scale the worker first:

```
heroku ps:scale resque=1 -a test-eagle
Scaling dynos... done, now running resque at 1:Free
```

Then when I check the workers, I see:

```
heroku ps:workers -a test-eagle
<app> is running 0 workers
```

What could be worng here? This is how my `Procfile` looks:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=* COUNT=1
```

Or is it because it is a free app which can only handle 1 web worker and no other dynos?

Edit:

When I check with `heroku ps -a <appname>` I see that just after starting the worker is crashed: `worker.1: crashed`. This is without doing anything in the application itself.

Comment: Have you tried to run this worker locally with `heroku local resque`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Well, I have a "free" app running that happens to run Puma, too.  So, I updated Procfile as follows:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=* COUNT=1
```

After that, I pushed the app to Heroku and ran heroku ps:scale, as you specified.  It worked as follows:

```
D:\Bitnami\rubystack-2.2.5-3\projects\kctapp>heroku ps -a kctapp
=== web (Free): bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb (1)
web.1: up 2016/06/06 19:38:24 -0400 (~ 1s ago)


D:\Bitnami\rubystack-2.2.5-3\projects\kctapp>heroku ps:scale resque=1 -a kctapp
Scaling dynos... done, now running resque at 1:Free

D:\Bitnami\rubystack-2.2.5-3\projects\kctapp>heroku ps -a kctapp
=== web (Free): bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb (1)
web.1: up 2016/06/06 19:38:24 -0400 (~ 51s ago)

=== resque (Free): env TERM_CHILD=1 bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=* COUNT=1 (1)
resque.1: crashed 2016/06/06 19:39:18 -0400 (~ -3s ago)
```

Note that it did crash.  But, I don't have any code running there, so that could be why?  Also, note that I use the "heroku ps" command as "heroku ps:workers" for me throws an error saying it is deprecated.

This is my config/puma.rb, if that helps:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 4)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 8)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 5000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'
```

---

With edit: I missed the scale command...

See scaling in Heroku [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling).  The options that I see are web, worker, rake or console, not resque.  I tried your command and it didn't recognize "that formation".  I'm curious about it.

Checking a free app, it does not give you the option to add a worker dyno.  Checking a hobby app, you can add workers to it.  With professional apps, you can mix and match the dyno type between web and worker using 1X, 2X, and Performance dynos.

Comment: I tried both things: renaming `resque` to `worker` and changing the plan from free to hobby. But with the same result.

Comment: @John My Heroku Toolkit gives me totally different responses than yours.  I am on Windows, but the Heroku command basically calls their environment, so I am surprised at the differences.  I was going to try it on my Ubuntu system, only to discover that it is not available at the moment.  In any case, what does Heroku Version tell you?  I get: heroku/toolbelt/3.43.3 (i386-mingw32) ruby/2.1.7 and 
heroku-cli/5.2.18-f850f09 (windows-amd64) go1.6.2

Comment: The crash was unrelated to the Heroku scaling, it was a not correct setup of the Redis environment variable which caused the crash. That has now been solved and now the worker is working fine. Thanks!